# PHP Regex get everything outside of two tags

Tags: php, regex

I've got a String in the following format:

```
firstlayer{secondlayer;secondlayer,secondlayer};firstlayer{secondlayer;secondlayer}
```

I now want to exclude all values between the "{}" Tags, so that I can simply explode the String with the semicolon. -> I want to get all the first layer values.

EDIT:
My first try had been this:

```
preg_match_all("(.*?)~\{\}~(.*?)", $string,$match);
```

but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: try to write some code ... then, show your efforts

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'firstlayer{secondlayer;secondlayer,secondlayer};firstlayer{secondlayer;secondlayer}';
if (preg_match_all('~(\w+)\{(.*?)\}~', $str, $m)) {
    print_r($m);
}
```

output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => firstlayer{secondlayer;secondlayer,secondlayer}
            [1] => firstlayer{secondlayer;secondlayer}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => firstlayer
            [1] => firstlayer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => secondlayer;secondlayer,secondlayer
            [1] => secondlayer;secondlayer
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace you matches with a blank string, using following regex. [demo:](https://regex101.com/r/bWLgex/1)

```
{[^}]*}
```

Or you can split directly on `;(?=[^}]*(?:{[^{}]*})+)`